# Do I need SSL even with PayPal transaction?

Tags: ssl, paypal

In my website, I have a Product Order Form. When a fills the necessary details and clicks Submit, the control is transferred to PayPal for processing transaction. I have a business account.

I want to know whether I need SSL for my Product Purchase Page. I am not asking any details of credit card but simply directing to PayPal site to get it done.

Answer (score 5):

I won't buy from a site that doesn't have SSL on its own site -- login details, anything that gets passed over should *not* be in cleartext. There will be some customer information being passed, and it provides me (and many others I know of) with peace of mind.

Comment: True, but to extend on this a bit: assuming the PayPal URLs are all HTTPS, then HTTPS on one's own domain does NOT make the payments any more secure.

Comment: Not more secure on the payment side, no, but potentially more secure in general, as there are likely to be details that would useful to an attacker being transmitted to/from the site.

Comment: If the site requires (or even allows) login/registration, yes, SSL should be supported.   If there is nothing other than product selection and a handoff to PayPal, it isn't really necessary.   The Firesheep release highlighted how trivial it is for to get access to site information and credentials if non-SSL access is allowed for logged-in users.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is used for secure transaction. but in today's date SSL is primarily required for web site. As it will also secure your important data like Payment Form Details and other billing related details.

Personally I feel SSL should be there for more secure business.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an SSL for your site. Even if  you are not charging Credit Card on  your site or using paypal to collect payments.

As you are asking user to put their login details and personal information like address, profile image etc. SSL is strongly recommended in today's trend to protect customer's sensitive information. **Even facebook and twitter is also using SSL to protect their user's data.** Try to go to change  your account data on facebook and you will see **https** there

You may check which SSL suits your needs by this link http://mycheapssl.com/index.php?route=common/whichSSL

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "it depends". If all you have is a simple shopping cart that doesn't store any user information, and you have all the money processed by PayPal where the cards are entered through their interface, I wouldn't bother with the SSL. So someone wants to snoop the products that are getting bought? Not really a big deal.

Checking Amazon, I notice that even they don't start encrypting things until you move into active checkout, or your personal account page.